# Output caching with location=server not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I have implemented outputcaching on Action method of controller with

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "ID", VaryByHeader="User-Agent", Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
public ActionResult MyAction(int ID)
{
    _logger.Error("call-" + ID);
}
```

and I have made log entry within this action. So, My problem is Output caching with location=Server calls this action method every time. It should not call every-time.

So, what's the problem with this?

When I changed Caching location i.e location=Client then only first time it calls the method. Then afterwards action method not called.

Comment: How long are you leaving it before you make a second call?

Comment: I have set Duration=60 sec & after 1st request I have clicked after 4-5sec but it doesn't retrieve from caching.

Comment: And it's the same ID every time for each request?

Comment: Yes, same ID every time.

Comment: Can we see the definition of the action method?

Comment: sure, you can..I have edited on my question

Comment: What happens if you remove your `VaryByHeader` value?  Do you need it to return new values for each different `User-Agent`?  `User-Agent` has the version number of the browser/device that you're using and all sorts of other information.  This could lead to multiple calls to your action method

Comment: Ok, then "VaryByHeader" is not necessary..I will remove it..But still every time make calls to action method.

Comment: Is the id being bound successfully to variable `ID`?

Comment: Yes, I get the value of id in log entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying output caching on the ChildAction? I know you have not written ChildAction attribute in your question but just asking for confirmation ? If it is then you can't use output caching on which are not Child Actions. You need to use [this](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3) caching plugin if you want to use output caching without child action.

Comment: It is not a ChildAction. But thank you for your valuable answer.

Comment: That's what I am saying. If it's not a child action then you can't use MVC Inbuild Caching. You need to use donut caching.

Comment: Ok..I get it. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help you guys

Comment: Very Happy to get help from you.

Comment: what is the reason non childactions cant be cached with output caching? I have a plugin which returns json data and I want to cache this? I must use donut outputcache?

Comment: I am not sure but i think its by design which prevents this.